# R : how to extract elements with the same index from two lists to write a function

Tags: r, list, function, lapply, quanteda

I am trying to write a function to calculate R1 lexical richness measure. The formula is as follows:

R1 = 1 - ( F(h) - h*h/2N) )

where N is the number of tokens, h is the Hirsch point, and F(h) is the cumulative relative frequencies up to that point. Using `quanteda` package I managed to calculate the Hirsch point.

To create my data I had to chunk each text in an increasing manner. Therefore, the input is a list of chunked texts within another list. To avoid nested lists, I changed chunked lists into character. (meaning within each character vector, there are different separate texts).

```
a <- c("The truck driver whose runaway vehicle rolled into the path of an express train and caused one of Taiwan’s worst ever rail disasters has made a tearful public apology.", "The United States is committed to advancing prosperity, security, and freedom for both Israelis and Palestinians in tangible ways in the immediate term, which is important in its own right, but also as a means to advance towards a negotiated two-state solution.")
a1 <- c("The 49-year-old is part of a team who inspects the east coast rail line for landslides and other risks.", "We believe that this UN agency for so-called refugees should not exist in its current format.")
a2 <- c("His statement comes amid an ongoing investigation into the crash, with authorities saying the train driver likely had as little as 10 seconds to react to the obstruction.", " The US president accused Palestinians of lacking “appreciation or respect.", "To create my data I had to chunk each text in an increasing manner.", "Therefore, the input is a list of chunked texts within another list.")
a3 <- c("We plan to restart US economic, development, and humanitarian assistance for the Palestinian people,” the secretary of state, Antony Blinken, said in a statement.", "The cuts were decried as catastrophic for Palestinians’ ability to provide basic healthcare, schooling, and sanitation, including by prominent Israeli establishment figures.","After Donald Trump’s row with the Palestinian leadership, President Joe Biden has sought to restart Washington’s flailing efforts to push for a two-state resolution for the Israel-Palestinian crisis, and restoring the aid is part of that.")
txt <-list(a,a1,a2,a3)

    
library(quanteda)
DFMs <- lapply(txt, dfm)
txt_freq <- function(x) textstat_frequency(x, groups = docnames(x), ties_method = "first")
Fs <- lapply(DFMs, txt_freq)

get_h_point <- function(DATA) {
  fn_interp <- approxfun(DATA$rank, DATA$frequency)
  fn_root <- function(x) fn_interp(x) - x
  uniroot(fn_root, range(DATA$rank))$root
}

s_p <- function(x){split(x,x$group)}  
tstat_by <- lapply(Fs, s_p)
h_values <-lapply(tstat_by, vapply, get_h_point, double(1))
```

To calculate the cumulative relative frequencies up to h_point`F(h)`—the sum of frequencies that are less than or equal to the h point value(of the same frequencies) divided by the total number of the frequencies added up— to put in R1, I need two values; one of them needs to be `$frequency` from `tstat_by` and the other must be the corresponding h point from `h_values`.

```
fh <- function(X,Y) {subset(tstat_by[[X]][[Y]], rank <= h_values[[X]][[Y]])}
```

this function extracts frequencies and ranks up to h point. consider the following:

```
fh31 <- subset(tstat_by[[3]][["text1"]], rank <= h_values[[3]][["text1"]])   #produces a list within which there are frequencies up to h point.
F1_1 <-sum(fh31$frequency) / length(fh31$frequency)    #the cumulative relative frequency up to h_point
R1_1 <-1 - ( F1_1 - h_values[[3]][["text1"]] * h_values[[3]][["text1"]] / 2 * sum(tstat_by[[3]][["text1"]]$frequency)    #produces the lexical richness value (R1)

fh32 <- subset(tstat_by[[3]][["text2"]], rank <= h_values[[3]][["text2"]])
F1_2 <-sum(fh32$frequency) / length(fh32$frequency)

fh33 <- subset(tstat_by[[3]][["text3"]], rank <= h_values[[3]][["text3"]])
F1_3 <-sum(fh33$frequency) / length(fh33$frequency)

fh34 <- subset(tstat_by[[3]][["text4"]], rank <= h_values[[3]][["text4"]])
F1_4 <-sum(fh34 $frequency) / length(fh34 $frequency)
```

the help I need is with the `X` and `Y` arguments of the function above. how do I define them to use `lapply` for `tstat_by`? Please note that the goal is to write a function to calculate R1, and what I`ve put here is what has been done in this regard.

Comment: @IRTFM hi. sorry, my bad. the correct phrasing would be " a character vector". I just added a simple sample to work with. my input data is a large list because of which I`ve  put a,a1,a2 into a list.

Comment: @IRTFM so sry. should`ve mentioned "newbie alert!" at the beginning :). the reproducible sample makes more sense now. Have a look. is there a way to debug the mapply?

Comment: If you want F(h) for any particular item than you need to describe it in detail (list?, vector?) and then write a function to return it. A description of "cumulative relative frequencies up to h_point" is not specific enough for me to write code. Why don't you use tstat[[3]] as an example and walk us through how to calculate what you consider to be the correct answer for that instance. Look at `F <- function(X,Y) {subset(tstat_by[[X]][[Y]], rank <= h_values[[X]][[Y]])}` and then apply it item-by-item to your `tstat_by` and `h_values` lists.

Comment: @IRTFM I really appreciate the time and energy you are putting into this. I've tried to put all this together, but my problem is still with the two arguments I need to define. have another look. just edited the codes.

Answer (score 0):

It's better practice to build the names of the list items inside the `list()` function call. That way you don't end up with a lot of "loose" names in your workspace. These are often the source of confusing error messages.

```
txt <- list( 
  a = c("The truck driver whose runaway vehicle rolled into the path of an express train and caused one of Taiwan’s worst ever rail disasters has made a tearful public apology.", "The United States is committed to advancing prosperity, security, and freedom for both Israelis and Palestinians in tangible ways in the immediate term, which is important in its own right, but also as a means to advance towards a negotiated two-state solution."),
  a1 = c("The 49-year-old is part of a team who inspects the east coast rail line for landslides and other risks.", "We believe that this UN agency for so-called refugees should not exist in its current format."),
  a2 = c("His statement comes amid an ongoing investigation into the crash, with authorities saying the train driver likely had as little as 10 seconds to react to the obstruction.", " The US president accused Palestinians of lacking “appreciation or respect.", "To create my data I had to chunk each text in an increasing manner.", "Therefore, the input is a list of chunked texts within another list."),
  a3 = c("We plan to restart US economic, development, and humanitarian assistance for the Palestinian people,” the secretary of state, Antony Blinken, said in a statement.", "The cuts were decried as catastrophic for Palestinians’ ability to provide basic healthcare, schooling, and sanitation, including by prominent Israeli establishment figures.","After Donald Trump’s row with the Palestinian leadership, President Joe Biden has sought to restart Washington’s flailing efforts to push for a two-state resolution for the Israel-Palestinian crisis, and restoring the aid is part of that.")
           )
```

This didn't succeed because character indexing appears to be more flexible than numeric indexed assignments as can be seen below:

```
F <- list() # need to put a name in the workspace before assignments by indexing
for( Ls in seq_along(tstat_by) ){ 
  for (items in seq_along(tstat_by[[ls]])){
    F[[Ls]][[items]] <- #doesn't work (throws error)
      R[[Ls]][[items]] <-
```

After struggling to use numeric indices on the LHS I gave up and got immediate success with character indices.

If you use character indexing into just a few objects, you avoid creating an unknown number of loose objects and instead keep them all in one (or two as in this case) structure. We'll call them `F` and `R`

```
str(tstat_by)
str(h_value)
F <- list()
R <- list() # need list names in the workspace before indexed assignments
for( Ls in names(tstat_by) ){  
  for (item in names(h_values[[Ls]]) ){  
        #produces a list within which there are frequencies up to h point.
        temp <-  subset(tstat_by[[Ls]][[item]], rank <= h_values[[Ls]][[item]])  
        #the calc cumulative relative frequency up to h_point
      F[[Ls]][item] <- sum(temp$frequency) / length(temp$frequency)  
        #produces the lexical richness value (R1)
      R[[Ls]][[item]] <- 1 - ( F[[Ls]][[item]] - 
                               h_values[[Ls]][[item]] * h_values[[Ls]][[item]] / 
                                      2 * sum(tstat_by[Ls][[item]]$frequency) )
                      }}
```

This is not my area of domain knowledge so I have no idea whether the magnitudes or signs of these results are correct. (One of the fundamentals of writing a good question is to specify what a correct answer would look like.)

```
> R
$a
$a$text1
[1] -1

$a$text2
[1] -2.5


$a1
$a1$text1
[1] -1

$a1$text2
[1] 0


$a2
$a2$text1
[1] -1.5

$a2$text2
[1] 0

$a2$text3
[1] -1

$a2$text4
[1] -1


$a3
$a3$text1
[1] -2.5

$a3$text2
[1] -2

$a3$text3
[1] -1.5
```

Comment: hi. quick question. why didn't you open a list in `temp` before the loops as well?

Comment: Because I didn't intend to keep the value around. But maybe you should make it an indexed assignment too? Sometimes there are scoping issues in for loops that I don't understand. Might be safer to do so.